# Is there a way to hide the adhesive line from iron-on edge banding

Tags: edge-banding

I applied iron-on edge banding to the edges of a piece of veneered MDF. The edge banding and the veneer on the MDF are both walnut. The adhesive on the back of the edge banding is white and is quite visible against the dark walnut. I'm not planning on staining before applying finish.

Any suggestions for how to hide the adhesive line?

Comment: a black or brown marker?

Comment: If you were just starting, I'd suggest applying the edge banding before the veneer, so that that edge is covered, but too late for that now.

Comment: How thick is the edge banding? How thick is the adhesive line?

Comment: Check the solubility of the adhesive in an inconspicuous spot, using a Q-tip. Start with mineral spirits and then denatured alcohol. If one of them works then with care you might be able to wipe away the visible portion of the glue line that sits on the surface, without undermining the main bond. If that's a non-starter then running one quick line using a touch-up marker as already suggested by @bowlturner is the only fix that makes sense to me. Run the tip of the marker along a straight edge, or [finger-gauge it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztMsZ.png), so you end up with a single, neat line.

Comment: @Caleb The Edge banding is about 0.025 in thick. The adhesive line is a small fraction of that, probably only a few thousandths of an inch.

Answer (score 3):

> Any suggestions for how to hide the adhesive line?

If the banding is thick enough, you could use a [string inlay tool](https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/tools/hand-tools/inlay-and-veneering-tools/69874-veritas-string-inlay-tool-system) to cut a narrow groove where the adhesive is. Then inlay some stringing (very thin strips of wood) to fill the groove. You could use more walnut if you just want to get rid of the line -- the stringing should mostly disappear.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about one of those. They are proud of their tools, but if you need 'em they're worth the price. I was going to suggest filling the resulting gap with a bit of glue and sanding dust from the project, but this tool cuts the filler strip, too!